# why this code not perfect work on iphone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cashapelayer

I want to exact bottom round shape on `UIImageView`. Here is my code that perfectly work on iPhone5 but when I run this code on iPhone6 that not work perfect..

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.imageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(150.0, 150.0)];


CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: probably because of auto layout, the bounds are not correct yet where you have placed that code.

Comment: use self.imageView.width*0.5 instead of 150 to get exact round. since screen size changes your imageviews width also changing. i guess this looks like the reason.

Comment: i used self.imageView.width*0.5 but result is same..

Comment: in which method u r putting this code?

Comment: That is the wrong place as suspected. Move it to `didLayoutSubviews` or something similar. It has to be somewhere where the actual layout is already present.